# date() not the same as what's showing at my taskbar

Tags: php, date, time

This might be one of the stupidest question but....ok this is my code

```
date("l, M-d-Y, H:i:s")
```

but somehow the output shows when I run it through my computer instead of a server

```
Saturday, Feb-16-2013, 00:21:49
```

and my computer time is actually

```
Friday, Feb-15-2013, 16:21:49
```

and when I uploaded it into a server to try the code this is what it showed

```
Friday, Feb-15-2013, 19:21:59
```

Any reason why the `date()`is few hours ahead and the time is different when I upload to a server.....
I used the code P and e and Timezone identifier shows UTC with +00:00(GMT)
but I believe my GMT should be -08:00 or +08:00 I forgot.
Did I do anything wrong with the codes or just some settings I need to adjust with my computer?  Because this happens to both my laptop and desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should adjust timezone before accessing the date. In php there's a function to set the timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");  //setting timezone
date("l, M-d-Y, H:i:s");
```

Here's the list of all timezone

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini for date.timezone:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone

e.g. date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"

or you can use

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php